# What Eclipse JavaFX project files to upload to GitHub

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, git, github

I have a project i'm working on that I want to upload to GitHub. It has eclipse project files and an fxbuild file. I'm creating an app that uses jdbc to connect to a mysql database and so i'm using the connector J. This is open source, https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j,  and so I wont upload that jar to GitHub but rather use GitHub submodules to use the ConnectorJ repository in my repository. Is this a good idea? The project structure looks like this:

```
.settings
bin
src
.classpath
.project
build.fxbuild
connectorj.jar
```

I'm wondering which files I should upload to GitHub from this project? shall I just upload everything and use the connector J repository as a submodule? is it ok to remove the fxbuild file or shall I upload that too? Any guidance would be appreciated, Thankyou.

Comment: Upload what you need to get it working again on another PC

Comment: i just wrote out the folders and files, should look familiar to anyone who has used eclipse right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only upload `src` and `build` files (files that are needed by a build tool). There should be no libraries (binaries) - you should provide them via some build tool like `Maven` or `Gradle`.
As I see currently you are not using any of them - thus you'll have issues in building the project on other PC's.

Typical JavaFX project files should look like this: https://github.com/TheItachiUchiha/MediaPlayerFX

I suggest refactoring your app to use e.g. Maven.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking Maven may be the solution but I was not shore, I also have never used it before so I was a bit reluctant. I suppose I'll have to learn it then. Thank you for the answer.